# NestJs Error: Cannot find module '../app.module'

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, nestjs

Аfter i use 'npm start' command, here is the error.

```
Error: Cannot find module '../app.module'
Require stack:
- E:\Egor\egor-internship-backend\dist\main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Egor\egor-internship-backend\dist\main.js:7:20)     
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
```

nest -v  10.1.16
node -v  v18.17.1

While for some reason in dist/main.js file, ../ is put in the path to the app.module instead of ./ or just the require("app.module");

```
const _appmodule = require("../app.module");
```

But the joke is that such an error is only on Windows. Everything works fine on Linux and MacOS.

Has anyone had this problem and can tell me how to solve it.

## Сonfigs below

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es2022",
    "noEmit": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitOverride": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./dist/tsbuildinfo.json",
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.build.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  }
}
```

**nest-cli.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "builder": "swc",
    "typeCheck": true
  }
}
```

I tried to reinstall the nodejs, nest sli, webstorm, start in dev/debug/prod mode, delete dist and node_modules, but it does not help.

[My project directory tree schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lF5K.png)

Comment: Fixed error by changing "baseUrl": "./src" to "baseUrl": "./"